# Crontab isn't deleting the files in a folder

Tags: cron

I have a crontab that is working fine and I added another line to delete files within a specific folder every Thursday at 11:30pm on Wednesday. Today is Friday but it's not working. It didn't delete the files in the /downloads folder.

```
55 23 * * 4-6 /usr/html/sched/restart.sh > /usr/html/sched/sched.log
30 23 * * 4 rm -rf /usr/html/sched/downloads/*
```

What am I missing? Why is this not working?

This is the server `date`:

```
Fri Oct  1 11:07:33 UTC 2021
```

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this

Answer (score 1):

This line in `cron`

```
30 23 * * 4 rm -rf /usr/html/sched/downloads/*
```

run at 23:30 every Thursday. To make it run on Friday you need to change it as this:

```
30 23 * * 4,5 rm -rf /usr/html/sched/downloads/*
```

to have run it every day it should be:

```
30 23 * * * rm -rf /usr/html/sched/downloads/*
```